# Simulate Spot Process with Forward Variance (Bergomi)

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, stochastic-volatility, simulations

I am reading Bergomi's book (Stochastic Volatility Modeling), and in section **8.7 The two-factor model** (page 326), the following dynamics are given:

\begin{align}
dS_t     &= \sqrt{\xi_t^t}\,S_t\,dW_t^S\\
d\xi_t^T &= 2\,\nu\,\xi_t^T\,\alpha_\theta\,\Big(
    (1-\theta)\,e^{-k_1(T-t)}\,dW_t^1 + 
    \theta    \,e^{-k_2(T-t)}\,dW_t^2
\Big)
\end{align}

In section **7.3.1 Simulating the N-factor model** (page 223), it is described that the spot process $S$ over 1 time interval can be discretized as
\begin{equation}
    \delta \ln S \ =\ ...\ +\ \sqrt{\xi_t^t}\, \delta W^S
\end{equation}

But how do we simulate $\xi_t^t$ (which specifically uses $t=T$)? Do we simulate multiple $\xi_t^T$ for various $T$? But then how do we get back values for $\xi_t^t$?

I am probably struggling to understand the notation, because $\xi_t^t$ would suggest that $e^{-k_1(T-t)} = e^{-k_1(t-t)} = 1$, since $t=T$. So parameter $k_1$ becomes irrelevant, which doesn't make sense.

In general, I just want to simulate a variance process $V_t$ such that I can also simulate the spot process as per $dS_t = \sqrt{V_t}\,S_t\,dW_t^S$. But I am struggling to tie the dynamics of $\xi_t^T$ back to $V_t$.

Any help on how to understood this notation, how to simulate $\xi_t^t$, and how to get $V_t$ from $\xi_t^T$ would be greatly appreciated.

---

*References:*

- Paper [Smile Dynamics II](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1493302) by Lorenzo Bergomi
- Book [Stochastic Volatility Modeling](https://www.lorenzobergomi.com) by Lorenzo Bergomi